# Webpage calls onclick handler even after validator is fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

We've got a web application written with VS2005, running on an ASP.NET 2.0 platform, which has a problem.

This is the code:

```
<td>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ibInsertEmpty_4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ok_green.png"
   OnClick="gv_mwl_EmptyInsert" />
</td>
<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="emptyMWL_ID" runat="server" Width="6em"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valemptyMWL_ID" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="emptyMWL_ID" ErrorMessage="<br>Link ID must not be empty!"
    SetFocusOnError="true" display="Dynamic" />
</td>
```

which is suppose to show an error if the user clicks the button when the textbox is empty.
Well, that happens, but even after the error is shown, it still calls the onclick handler gv_mwl_EmptyInsert, as if there was no error.

Why is this happening?

Unfortunately, I can't post a link to the website (because it's on an intranet, and it uses a database which requires authorisation), but I tried to make a small testcase which has the same problem, without success. So I don't know what to do now.

Comment: You need to get the status of RequiredFieldValidator using custom function or Page.IsValid when you click on the image button.

Comment: I can do that, yes. I mean, Page.IsValid does have the right value in the click handler. But it still feels like a kludge. In my experience, it shouldn't be necessary. There shouldn't even be a postback, as the validator can handle everything by itself using Javascript. Then why does the postback take place anyway?

Comment: If you prefer to use client side validation, check this: http://techbrij.com/709/client-side-validation-using-asp-net-validator-controls-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ValidationGroup="SomeValidationGroup"
```

To both the Button, and the validator

Comment: That doesn't help. Still the same result. And in my small testcase, I don't need it either, because it works as advertised, even without this.